# bind json data to input select

Tags: jquery, html

I am using one input select where i have to bind json data to this control.

Below is the input select used:

```html
<select id="ms" multiple="multiple" name="selector">
                            
</select>
```

Below is jquery used for bind data on page load:

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
        
        $('#ms').multipleSelect({
            width: '100%'
        });
        BindCategory();
  });
   function BindCategory()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Article/BindCategory",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {
                var sel = $('#ms');
                $.each(response.Categories, function (i, value) {
                    j=1;
                    sel.append('<option value="' + value + '">' + i + '</option>');

                    j++;
                });
            },
            error: function (er) {
                alert(er);
            }
        });
    }
```

in this bindcategory function i am running one loop to get value one by one and putting in html select control but after complete this process data is not binding in this control.

I added now screen shot of response for your reference in below:

[image: response data]

Comment: What error you facing??

Comment: can you show your consoled `response` array?

Comment: please debug your success function first and see if you have got the right response object back

Comment: Hi, I debugged it and i know i am getting the correct data. for your reference i edited my question above and added now the screen shot of response data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using https://github.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select multiselect plugin. If so, In the documentation it specifies to use `refresh` to reload the select if it dynamically fetches the data.

> If you’re dynamically adding/removing option tags on the original select via AJAX or DOM manipulation methods, call refresh to reflect the changes.

Try placing `$(elm).multipleSelect('refresh');` in your success function. Something like:

```
 success: function (response) {
            var sel = $('#ms');
            $.each(response.Categories, function (i, value) {
                j=1;
                sel.append('<option value="' + value + '">' + i + '</option>');

                j++;
            });
            sel.multipleSelect('refresh');
        },
```

Comment: Hey Nishanth, What a stick reply. Thanks dude your solution works for me. I am marking it as answer.

Comment: Np..happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code,

```
<select id="ms" multiple="multiple" name="selector"></select>
```

Below is the modified JS code.

```
function BindCategory(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (response) {
            var sel = $('#ms');
            $.each(response, function (i, value) {
                sel.append('<option value="' + value.name + '">' + value.name + '</option>');
            });
            sel.multipleSelect('refresh');
        },
        error: function (er) {
            console.log(er);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ms').multipleSelect({
        width: '100%'
    });

    BindCategory();
});
```

Just change the ajax url to your url and `sel.append('<option value="' + value.name + '">' + value.name + '</option>');` and this part of code as per your need. Let me know if its works for you. Below is the working fiddle if you want to test it. [Working fiddle. try it](https://jsfiddle.net/singhaloke/zg8xu4c2/5/)